# How to center icons in Flutter

Tags: flutter, frontend, icons, padding

I am working on the camera part in the Flutter application. On the bottom, there are two icons. One for the flash and one for the camera button. I would like for them to be centered on the screen. I was trying to make the red camera button appear in the center and the yellow flash icon would appear close to the camera button on the left side.
[image]

```
Widget controlRow() {
    return Ink(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Row(
          //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            const IconButton(
             
              onPressed: null,
              
              icon: Icon(
              
                //Icons.margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 5.0),
                Icons.flash_auto,
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
              iconSize: 50,
            ),

            IconButton( // circle button
                // padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                onPressed: takePicPressed,
                icon: const Icon( // icon: const Icon( 
                  Icons.lens_outlined,
                  color: Colors.red,

                  
                  
                
                ),
                iconSize: 90),

            const SizedBox(width: 50, height: 25) // 50 and 25
          ],
        ));
  }
```

> *I tried with the padding and Edge Insets but I do not understand what exactly Edge Insets do. Below I have listed some pieces of code that I
> have tried down below.*

```
/Icons.margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 5.0),
// padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed your code and attached a screenshot of what it looks like:

```
 Widget controlRow() {
    return Ink(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Center(
          heightFactor: 1,
          child: Wrap(
            crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const IconButton(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                onPressed: null,
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.flash_auto,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                ),
                iconSize: 50,
              ),
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.lens_outlined,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  iconSize: 90),
              const SizedBox(width: 50, height: 25)
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
```

[image]

The main idea was to just center these buttons, and I did this with the Wrap and Center widgets.

If my answer helped, then don't forget to mark it as correct (tick).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understood why you are using Sizedbox there. It is not necessary.

```
const SizedBox(width: 50, height: 25)
```

You have 3 choices here:

1. Add mainaxisalignment of Row to center:   `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center`
2. Wrap Row with Center widget `child: Center( child:Row(....) )`
3. Or add Spacer widget as first and last child of the Row.  `Row( children[ Spacer(), IconButton(....), IconButton(....), Spacer() ] )`

About EdgeInsets:
It is used when padding is needed. It means it helps to gave some space around the widget.
There are mainly four types using in common.

1. `EdgeInsets.only()` - to add padding to only sides we need like, left,right,top,bottom.
2. `EdgeInsets.fromLTRB` - to add padding to all sides. L- left , T- top , R- right, B - bottom.
3. `EdgeInsets.symmetric()` - to add padding symmetrically. `horizontal` will add padding to left and right equally. `vertical` will add padding to top and bottom equally.
4. `EdgeInsets.zero` - to remove all padding.
5. `EdgeInsets.all()` - to add padding from all sides equally.